# Solving With Iteration

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

I have trouble proving the following with the iteration technique:

$T(n) = T(n-1) + 4n$

$T(n-1) = T(n-2) + 4n - 4$

$T(n-2) = T(n-3) + 4n - 8$

$T(n-3) = T(n-4) + 4n - 12$

What is the general form?

Comment: I just want to prove T(n) = T(n-1) + 4n

Comment: What of the above is given, and what do you need to prove?

Comment: I just want to solve T(n) = T(n-1) + 4n with iteration

Comment: What do you mean by `solve it`? If you mean finding a closed form for $T(n)$ then that's what my answer does, you just need to fill-in the obvious last step. If you mean something else, please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $T_n \color{red}{- 2n^2} = T_{n-1} \color{red}{- 2n^2} +4n \color{red}{-2+2} = T_{n-1}-2(n-1)^2+2\,$, so $\,T_n-2n^2\,$ is an AP.

Comment: It is an arithmetic progression as noted.  However, the start is unspecified.

Comment: @herbsteinberg `the start is unspecified` That's correct, the OP asked for the `general form`, but the exact sequence cannot be determined unless $T_0$ is known.